# Why does the performane of Google ProtoBuf increase gradually

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am new to Google ProtoBuf. One thing I noticed is that the performance of ProtoBuf gradually increases as the number of encode/decode increases.

I have a test written in Java, which encodes a class and immediately decodes it. The same class is encoded/decoded for 1000 times.

The time taken is as follows, the first number is the time took for encoding and the second number is the time took for decoding, measured in microseconds.

```
 Proto: 886 , 993
 Proto: 888 , 997
 Proto: 850 , 1016
 Proto: 861 , 998
 Proto: 851 , 1055
 ......
 ......
 Proto: 469 , 545
 Proto: 469 , 555
 Proto: 403 , 612
 Proto: 421 , 713
 Proto: 374 , 535
 ......
 ......
 Proto: 186 , 477
 Proto: 189 , 473
 Proto: 186 , 476
 Proto: 186 , 700
 Proto: 190 , 483
 Proto: 194 , 464
 Proto: 186 , 397
 .......
 .......
 Proto: 110 , 135
 Proto: 107 , 125
 Proto: 115 , 134
 Proto: 111 , 142
 Proto: 131 , 136
 Proto: 108 , 124
 .......
 .......
 Proto: 82 , 107
 Proto: 79 , 100
 Proto: 78 , 100
 Proto: 85 , 101
 Proto: 69 , 68
 Proto: 67 , 66

 ......
 ......

 Proto: 73 , 69
 Proto: 71 , 69
 Proto: 85 , 83
 Proto: 73 , 68
 Proto: 74 , 72
 Proto: 74 , 68
 Proto: 71 , 68
 Proto: 71 , 76
 Proto: 72 , 68
 ......
 ......

 Proto: 33 , 28
 Proto: 34 , 28
 Proto: 47 , 32
 Proto: 35 , 28
 Proto: 33 , 28
 Proto: 34 , 29
 ......
 ......
 Proto: 36 , 45
 Proto: 44 , 29
 Proto: 34 , 28
 Proto: 34 , 28
```

These tests are all independent. I am wondering:

1. How ProtoBuf handles this and why it gradually increases the performance?
2. Why doesn't it reach its best performance at the beginning?
3. How can I tune ProtoBuf so that it reaches its best performance from the beginning?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It could well be a JVM thing, not a ProtoBuf thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is *typical* of Java: as part of the virtual machine, the JIT (Just-In-Time) compiler optimizes code that gets run extensively, and can steadily apply more detailed optimizations as the code gets run more, and the VM learns more about how the code behaves in practice.  For example, if a `List` variable is almost always an `ArrayList`, the JVM can optimize to behave best in that case.

There isn't really a way to change this: the compiler can't determine ahead of time whether one `if` condition is more probable than another, and other things the JIT needs to determine how to best optimize your code.